# Java.Security CertificateFactory.getInstance randomly failing

Tags: java, security, certificate, x509

I encountered a weird issue that results in my tests failing randomly. Please see the following example:

```
val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509")
```

I am trying to get an instance of the certificate factory in order to generate an X509Certificate from a file in my test resources folder. After running the tests a few times, I found out that this randomly fails, with the following exception:

```
X509 not found
java.security.cert.CertificateException: X509 not found
    at java.base@17/java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance
```

After some research on the internet, I found out that some people tend to use `X.509` in stead of `X509`.
Changing `CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509")` to `CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")` resulted in the exact same behaviour: About 75% of the time the tests passed, in the other cases it did not.

My final attempt was to fall back on `X.509` when attempting to get an instance of `X509` failed, like so:

```
val certificateFactory = try {
                CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509")
            } catch (ex: CertificateException) {
                println("CertificateFactory instance for X509 not found, attempting with X.509")
                CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
            }
```

This did not change the result of the tests.

Concluding from this little experiment, it appears that the CertificateFactory sometimes does contain an instance of both "X509" and "X.509", and sometimes it contains neither of those.
Is there a possibility that CertificateFactory sometimes doesn't get initialised properly, or something of the sort?

The code is written in Kotlin, running on the following Java versions:

```
openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17+35 (build 17+35)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17+35 (build 17+35, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I could not find much about this use case on the internet, so I'm trying my luck here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Meta: not really an answer, at least not yet, but too much for comments. I will delete if necessary.

I'm ignoring Kotlin because I don't *think* it does anything relevant here, though I could be wrong. In any case you should be able to test this specific feature in plain Java easily enough.

The JCA-standard type (aka algorithm) name for CertificateFactory [is `"X.509"` with the dot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-3A80CC46-91E1-4E47-AC51-CB7B782CEA7D) and always has been (back to Java 5 at least). I'm not sure if the PKCS11 provider can support this API, but if so it would vary depending on the underlying P11 device or library. (*Traditional* P11 devices, i.e. real HSMs, weren't involved in cert management and only limited processing, but over time P11 has been used, or perhaps abused, for such a wide range of things I hesitate to make any general claim about it.)

If you have [the *BouncyCastle* provider](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) installed, it does provide `"X509"` as an alias/synonym *in addition to* `"X.509"` (but never as a substitute).

I suggest you check at the point of attempt/failure what providers are configured -- something like

```
import java.security.*;
...
for( Provider p : Security.getProviders() ) System.out.println (p.getName());
```

If either SUN or BC is present, `getInstance("X.509")` should work, and if neither, I don't see how almost anything else you want to do in that JVM will work.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for taking the time to reply. I've implemented your suggestion. To my surprise, `Security.getProviders()` returns an empty array in the scenario where the tests fail. Whenever the tests do succeed, I'm getting an array with mainly "Sun" providers.

Is there any way this flaky behaviour is caused by the JRE/JDK I'm using?

Edit: By the way, I am not using Bouncycastle.

Comment: Yes, an empty providerlist is definitely bad news. All release of "the JRE/JDK" from normal builders like the Adoptium/Temurin you are using do not have this as supplied, although if you or someone (either intentionally or not) changes the JRE/conf/security/java.security file (below 9 was in JRE/lib/security) that could cause it, as could overriding that file by setting sysprop `java.security.properties` to a value beginning with `=`. Separately, if you're not using Bouncy there's no way `"X509"` should _ever_ work. ...

Comment: ... And while there should be and normally are several providers _beginning_ `Sun` (not all caps) -- [see the list in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-F41EE1C9-DD6A-4BAB-8979-EB7654094029) -- there should be and normally is only one named `SUN` which is the specific name I referenced and the one that implements `CertificateFactory` type `"X.509"` (as listed in that same doc).

Comment: For completeness I should have added that in addition to the java.security file being bad, the providerlist can also be screwed up by any (other) code run in your JVM.